# saving Data from different tables and input fields in one row

Tags: php

I can't figure out how to store all the data in one row.
When I use this code, the eventID, ticketName and ticketID are stored without a problem.

```
$sql = $con->query("INSERT INTO registratie(eventID, ticketName, ticketID)"
." SELECT eventID, ticketName, ticketID"
." FROM ticket WHERE ticketID = ".$_GET['ticketID'] ."");
```

Now I want to store also the &_SESSION["UserID"] and two input fields on the form ($PartnerFName and $PartnerLName)in the same row but this will not work.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['registreren'])) {

    session_start();

    $PartnerFName = $_POST['PartnerFName'];
    $PartnerLName = $_POST['PartnerLName'];
    $UserID = $_SESSION["UserID"];

$sql = $con->query("INSERT INTO registratie(eventID, ticketName, ticketID, UserID)"
." SELECT eventID, ticketName, ticketID"
." FROM ticket WHERE ticketID = ".$_GET['ticketID'] ." , '{$UserID}', '{$PartnerFName}', '{$PartnerLName}' ");
    }
?>
```

Can someone help me here?
Thanks!

Comment: you are trying to insert into 4 columns but you select only 3 values

Comment: You seem to be duplicating a lot of data here.  Why are you storing the ticket info on in the registration table?  At any rate, your INSERT statement is inserting only 4 columns, but you're listing 6 values.

Comment: do something like SELECT eventID, ticketName, ticketID," .$_GET['ticketID']."

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the PartnerFName && PartnerLName columns and put $UserID as integer. Like the following:

```
$sql = $con->query("INSERT INTO registratie(eventID, ticketName, ticketID, UserID, PartnerFName, PartnerLName)"
." SELECT eventID, ticketName, ticketID"
." FROM ticket WHERE ticketID = ".$_GET['ticketID'] ." , {$UserID}, '{$PartnerFName}', '{$PartnerLName}' ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Vlad to set me in the good diretion. I have changed the code and it works:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['registreren'])) {

    session_start();

    $PartnerFName = $_POST['PartnerFName'];
    $PartnerLName = $_POST['PartnerLName'];

$sql = $con->query("INSERT INTO registratie(eventID, ticketID, UserID, PartnerFName, PartnerLName)"
." SELECT eventID, ticketID, ".$_SESSION["UserID"].",'{$PartnerFName}','{$PartnerLName}' "
." FROM ticket WHERE ticketID = ".$_GET['ticketID'] ."") ;
    }       
?>
```